# AWS cannot access Laravel API from mobile browser on 4G/LTE network

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, react-native

I have deployed my first Laravel project on AWS and i am trying to communicate to my REACT NATIVE mobile app through the Laravel API.
The problem is that on WIFI network everything works perfectly but in 4G/LTE network i keep getting response error 500. I have tried changing the permissions on AWS but nothing is working

Answer (score 2):

Error 500 means its a server error not react native.